# apt-key is deprecated plex on a raspberry pi 3b

Tags: apt, ssh, raspberrypi, plex

Whats up guys, I'm still a huge noob and I don't understand what is going on even though there are similar problems and solutions.

I have a raspberry pi that i want to use for a nas. i followed the tutorial from network chuck on youtube and i am 19 minutes into the video [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gyMpI8csWis), im also following allong from his website [website](https://learn.networkchuck.com/courses/take/ad-free-youtube-videos/lessons/28458804-i-built-a-raspberry-pi-nas) and I'm at "install plex media server"(nr2).

I pasted this:

```
curl https://downloads.plex.tv/plex-keys/PlexSign.key | sudo apt-key add -
```

in the terminal and got this in return

```
Warning: apt-key is deprecated.
Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8))
```

From what i understand the way of doing things changed in april or something but as i sayed, im a super noob, i only started messing arround with this raspberry pi and the termenal this month, so sorry if it is a really easy solution lol

please comment what i should do (ill just coppy and paste), thanks

Here is the full thing but it might be useless, idk

```
 pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo curl https://downloads.plex.tv/plex-keys/PlexSign.key | sudo apt-key add -
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  3072  100  3072    0     0  22100      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 22100
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
```

Comment: It is better you ask this in raspberry pi forum on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been covered several times, as per the duplicate link above.

However, for that particular scenario, these commands might help you.

To install the key:

```
curl https://downloads.plex.tv/plex-keys/PlexSign.key | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/plex.gpg
```

To add the repo:

```
echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/plex.gpg] https://downloads.plex.tv/repo/deb public main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/plexmediaserver.list
```

Now you should be able to continue the walkthrough.